# Remover links que tenham certa string com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Boa noite gente boa...

Bom minha duvida e o seguinte, eu tenho uma lista de links...

```
<ul>
<li><a href="baixar.php?musica=teste-ativo.mp3">Musica 1</a></li>
<li><a href="baixar.php?musica=teste-desativado.mp3">Musica 2</a></li>
<li><a href="baixar.php?musica=teste-ativo.mp3">Musica 3</a><li>
<li><a href="baixar.php?musica=teste-desativado.mp3">Musica 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

bom, agora eu queria q apenas os links que tenham a string "desativado" na url, ficassem ocultas, com hide(); por exemplo

Att... Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o ["attribute contains selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) do jQuery para selecionar os links que contêm o string "desativado":

```
$("li > a[href*='desativado']").hide();
```

Note que isso vai esconder o texto, mas o item da lista continua aparecendo. O que você quer provavelmente é remover os elementos da lista, o que você pode fazer usando o `remove()` ([exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ccfqu6q/)):

```
$("li > a[href*='desativado']").parent().remove();
```

Comment: opa obrigado cara! funcionou! aproveitando! vamos variar a questao! e para remover os links que nao tenham "desativado" sem usar o seu codigo acima?
no caso todo link q tiver nao tiver "desativado"

usando uma condicao if

Comment: ah cara obrigado! ja consegui fazer com php! fico melhor! mas mesmo assim obrigado!